# Good tutorial on Windows filter driver development?

Tags: windows, driver

I'm an experienced C/C++ programmer, but i never created Windows drivers before. Currently i need to create a very simple keyboard filter driver that will "prohibit" some key combinations (for **illustrative** purpose - it will prevent "ctrl" and "a" to be pressed at same time by filtering out "a" keydown in keys "ctrl" keydown was detected and to keyup yet).

I want to solve this task by myself and self-educate a bit, but reading **all** required literature and tutorials will be kind of overkill and will take very long time :(. Is it any good windows drivers development tutorials i can use for my task in order to save time?

Comment: MS has an extensive documentation online.
A good place to start is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454832(v=vs.85).aspx - and follow the internal links per need. There are also a lot of free official online samples. In fact, you can find the **keyboard filter driver** that you seek in a sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Kbfiltr-WDF-Version-685ff5c4 There is also an MS-maintained forum for Kernel development (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/threads), they are responsive and serious.